# Yii2 get model relation named "relation" literally

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

Am confused as duck.
It is a great method `ActiveRecord->getRealtion($name)` which returns `ActiveQuery` if model have relation with `$name` and `null` if it haven't. And this method works perfectly for almost every name, but... "relation" literally.

But it would not be so confusing, if it would trigger some kind of exceptions or something, handled by framework, but it throws PHP's `ArgumentCountError`:

```
Too few arguments to function yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::getRelation(), 0 passed in /usr/src/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php on line 1244 and at least 1 expected
```

Really, this string of code

```
$models->getRelation('relation')
```

would throw that error and I do not know why.
What am I missing? Is it a reserved string in PHP, or some kind of PHP behavior, or what?
Please, explain me, what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've realized that.
It is Yii2 thing: `BaseActiveRecord->getRelation` have such code:

```
    $getter = 'get' . $name;
    try {
        // the relation could be defined in a behavior
        $relation = $this->$getter();
    } catch (UnknownMethodException $e) {
    ...
```

In case of `$name === 'relation'`, it would be `$getter === 'getRelation'`, which would call `$this->getRelation()` itself without any attributes, and this is causing an PHP error.

Comment: That's because relations in Yii2 are defined in models as methods named `getName()` that returns `ActiveQuery` describing the relation. You can choose the "Name" part of that method for yourself. But, to define relation named "relation" you would need to make `getRelation()` method and that would override the `BaseActiveRecord::getRelation()` breaking it even futher. So it's not a good idea to try to create relation named "relation".